# Carpe sciurum (sieze/harvest the squirrel?)

Tags: grammar-choice, declension, grammar-identification

Would 'carpe sciurum' be a functional translation of 'seize the squirrel'?
(As in to 'harvest' or 'pluck' the squirrel?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is simply to take the well-known phrase *carpe diem* and replace the word for 'day' with the word for 'squirrel,' then yes, *carpe sciurum* is grammatically correct.

As to whether the completed phrase actually means anything like 'Seize/harvest the squirrel' in a way that's at all analogous to 'Seize the day,' that's a different question. I'd say that, if it means anything, it means 'Tear the squirrel to pieces' (though I suppose it could also mean 'Make snarky comments about the squirrel behind its back').